# Symfony2/Doctrine Null Foreign Key Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have an entity that has a foreign key that I've set to be nullable in the database and annotations. When attempting to set this value to null before I persist it I get an error saying it expects an instance of the entity the foreign key is for and it got null.

```
$newGame->setGameTeamIdOne(null);
```

Comment: show the defination of your setGameTeamIdOne method.

Comment: public function setGameTeamIdOne(\MLBP\BeerBundle\Entity\TableTeam $gameTeamIdOne)
    {
     $this->gameTeamIdOne = $gameTeamIdOne;
    }

Comment: Replace the function header with: `public function setGameTeamIdOne(\MLBP\BeerBundle\Entity\TableTeam $gameTeamIdOne = null) ` or generate your entities again